# Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a number instead

Tags: json, swift, api, decodable

Having an issue with JSON parsing with swift 5 result type. Here is the following code that causes error.

This is my example JSON data.

```
[
  9129911,
  9129199,
  9127761,
  9128141,
  9128264,
  9127792,
  9129248,
  9127092,
  9128367,
  9038733
]
```

This is my fecthing code.

```
func fetchData(completion: @escaping (Result<[news],Error>) -> Void){
      guard let url = URL(string: base_URL) else { return }
      URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in

        if let error = error {
          completion(.failure(error))
          return
        }

        guard let jsonData = data else { return }
        do {

          let info = try JSONDecoder().decode([news].self, from: jsonData)
          //let userId = info
          completion(.success(info))

        }catch let error {
          completion(.failure(error))
        }


        }.resume()
    }
```

I am calling this function

```
FetchData { (result) in
      switch result {
      case .success(let info):
          self.users = info
            print(self.users)
      case .failure( let error):
          print(error)
      }
    }
```

and my self.users stands for

```
var users = [news]()
```

and my structure is ->

```
struct news: Decodable {

  let id: [Int]

}
```

Comment: Your JSON is a plain old array of numbers. But your code expects it to be a dictionary with a key of `"id"` whose value is an array of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is a simple array of integers, so you should just decode it like this:

```
let info = try JSONDecoder().decode([Int].self, from: jsonData)
```

A `[news]` array will correspond to a JSON structure like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": [1,2,3]
    },
    {
        "id": [4,5,6]
    }
]
```

They are very different.

I suggest you change the `news` struct to something like this:

```
struct News {
    let id: Int
}
```

And then after decoding, you can convert the decoded data into a `[News]` like this:

```
func fetchData(completion: @escaping (Result<[News],Error>) -> Void){
  guard let url = URL(string: base_URL) else { return }
  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in

    if let error = error {
      completion(.failure(error))
      return
    }

    guard let jsonData = data else { return }
    do {

      let arrayOfInts = try JSONDecoder().decode([Int].self, from: jsonData)
      let info = arrayOfInts.map(News.init)
      completion(.success(info))

    }catch let error {
      completion(.failure(error))
    }


    }.resume()
}
```